# Javascript Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: edit is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I am calling a function named edit from an onclick event as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    ...

    $.each(data, function (key, val) {
      ...

      var td11 = $('<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="edit();" />')
        .attr("name",val.Id);

      $(tr2).append(td11);
      $(table1).append(tr2);
    });

    $("#cers").append(table1);
```

The function is defined outside the $.each loop, inside $(document).ready, as follows

```
function edit() {
  alert("Id ");
}
```

When i click on Edit button, Chrome shown error : Uncaught ReferenceError: edit is not defined.

No other errors.

Comment: Are there any other errors inside the console?

Comment: try reproducing the bug in jsfiddle.net please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have defined `edit` function not in global scope. It should be defined outside not only `$.each` loop, but outside `$(document).ready` and etc. For example this works:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function func () {
        alert('func');
      }

      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('<a href="#" onClick="func();">link</a>').appendTo('#container');
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But it is better to bind event in javascript, in your case:

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
  // ... some code
  var td11 = $('<input type="button" value="Edit">')
    .click(edit)
    .attr('name', val.Id);

  $(tr2).append(td11);
  $(table1).append(tr2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Mixing functionality (javascript) in with layout (HTML) is not recommended, and makes for a less-than-optimal development experience as the scope of your project grows larger. It is better to use jQuery to bind to the click event on that element as follows:

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    /* . . . */
    var td11 = $('<input type="button" value="Edit" />').attr("name",val.Id);
    $(tr2).append(td11);
    $(table1).append(tr2);
});
$("#cers").append(table1);

$('input[value="Edit"]').click( edit );

function edit() {
    alert("Id ");
}
```

Alternatively, with this style, you don't even need a named function:

```
$('input[value="Edit"]').click( function() {
    alert("Id ");
});
```

If using the named function, however, it is important that `edit` be defined within the same scope where the event handler is bound (i.e. in the same scope where you call `.click(...)`).